# AngularJS: How could I specify an alternate startup path with ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to define a startup path for `ui-router` that is different from `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`. Or is there maybe a trick to fool `ui-router` into navigating to a different path at startup?

Comment: What's wrong with using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()`?

Comment: I want a startup path and a fallback/otherwise path which is different from the startup path. Hence, the question.

Comment: Writing something like this in your module.config would make a trick. $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/dashboard');

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the callback method of [`otherwise()`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#otherwise-for-invalid-routes) to choose the default path based on the current one, eg

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    return $location.path() === '/' ? '/startup' : '/fallback';
});
```

---

Otherwise, I'd just make a "home" or "root" state for the `/` URL and redirect elsewhere

```
$stateProvider.state('root', {
    url: '/',
    onEnter: function($state) {
        // this is so you don't interrupt the current state transition
        $state.transition.then(function() {
            return $state.go('startup-state');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is '/' is a legitimate path. If the user navigates to '/' at a later time they get redirected again. Also, I just cannot check against the startup path to redirect to the fallback because if the user refreshes then the previous path is again the startup path and intended destination is also the startup path.

Comment: While your answer was not exactly what I was looking for it gave me the idea need to solve the problem. The code I ended up with looks like this:

```
let startup = true;
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
    if (startup) {
     startup = false;
     return '/startup';
    }
    else {
     return '/fallback';
    }
});
```